# How can I remove hex high value from a string?

Tags: java

How can I remove hex high value from a string? eg. in my database a name is stored in hex high value (`ŸŸŸŸŸŸŸŸŸACB`), I need to remove `ŸŸŸŸŸŸŸŸŸ` and get only `ABC`.

Comment: "hex high"? You mean keep only hexadecimal character?

Comment: it's just a string, so use your db's string operations...?

Comment: Maybe give us some more example inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 0):

```
String result = value.replaceAll("[^\x20-\x7e]", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static String trimCharacters( String strToBeTrimmed)
{
    strToBeTrimmed = strToBeTrimmed.replaceAll("\\x00", null);  // remove all NULLs
    // similar for the others

    // this always comes last
    strToBeTrimmed = strToBeTrimmed.replaceAll("\\s{20}",null);    // remove whitespace in 20-char chunks

    return strToBeTrimmed;
}
```